# How to prevent a TextView resize the parent LinearLayout - Android

Tags: android, textview, horizontalscrollview

I have a `LinearLayout` that covers the entire width of the screen, inside I have a random number of `TextView` (7 in this example). I want all the `TextView` are the same size, so I put the attribute `android:layout_weight="1"` in each.

When there is not text in the TextView everything works fine:

[image]

but when I add the text corresponding to each `TextView`, the size of `Textview` change, not keep the weight and resize the `LinearLayout`

[image]

This is only part of the design of my Activity, so I recreated it in a new xml to see if the error persists.
And I have noticed that this only happens when the `LinearLayout` is inside of a `HorizontalScrollView`

When it is not, I get the expected result:

[image]

My xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="LONG TEXT"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009FDC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:text="LONG TEXT"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009FDC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:text="LONG TEXT"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009FDC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:text="LONG TEXT"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009FDC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:text="LONG TEXT"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009FDC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:text="LONG TEXT"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009FDC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:text="LONG TEXT"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009FDC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Anyone know how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: set your height and width for textView dynamically.

Comment: set text size property in your TextView.

Comment: as you don't want scroll your view why you put your view inside `horizontalScrollView` ?

Comment: Ok think of a tablet placed horizontally
As I mentioned, I have a random number of TextView, and I want them all have the same size. However, when I switch to portrait mode each TextView would be too small, so I add a minimum width and horizontalScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i tried with table layout

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_dashboared"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="7" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#009FDC"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="LONG TEXT"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#009FDC"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="LONG TEXT"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#009FDC"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="LONG TEXT"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#009FDC"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="LONG TEXT"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#009FDC"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="LONG TEXT"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#009FDC"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="LONG TEXT"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#009FDC"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="LONG TEXT"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I try this and work excelent, but how I can set minWidth to each TextView? I can´t make that work

Comment: y u want  to set minwidth?

Comment: Think of a tablet placed horizontally, the size of each TextView looks ok However, but when I switch to portrait mode each TextView would be too small, so I add a minimum width and scroll the content.

Comment: try with `android:minEms="2"` ...width shub be wrap content

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your xml a bit. Try this and let me know the result

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <TextView
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add android:weightSum= doesn´t make any difference but, thanks for the help

Comment: Width of all the textview should be fill_parent

Comment: Is the same, no difference

Comment: they have the same size because they have the same size, try setting different text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LONG TEXTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#009FDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LONG TEXT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image]